# Object reference not set to an instance of an object In XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I am new to iPhone and using XML in my application where i need to send one image to the server's one specific folder. For the same i am using the code :

```
NSString *filename = @"Image";
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imageView image], 90);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://111.111.11.1/webservices.asmx/PutImage"];
```

//url is : http://111.111.11.1/webservices.asmx/PutImage?ImgIn=image.jpg

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"--------1473780983"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"\n\n\nreturnString : %@",returnString);
```

I am getting message like : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in return string. Can anybody guide me with some solution?

Comment: your returnData is empty

Comment: @sicKo : Can you help me with the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Try my code that i m using....

//imageview is a UIImageView

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 100);


// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/upload";

// setting up the request object now

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type

 You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
 as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
self.returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is the same code I am using. I have doubt in the line [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; What I need to pass in place of name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg

Comment: name = your NSData *imageData and file name = your NSString *filename

Answer (score 0):

To upload data from your iPhone to your server:

```
  - (void)sendImage {

              NSData *postData = [nsdata from your original image];
              NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

              // Init and set fields of the URLRequest
              NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
              [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
              [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://yoururl.domain"]]];

              [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
              [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
              [request setHTTPBody:postData];

              NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

              if (connection) {
                    // Return data of the request
                       NSData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
               }
             [request release];

       }
```

Comment: In the line [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://yoururl.domain"]]]; what if I want to pass my parameter like http://yoururl.domain then Img=image.png. I suppose that image.png will be fetched by the nsdata but how abt the Parameter?

Comment: I knw but I am asking about the parameter.That i need to pass for that image in the URL. Like imgName=something.png